# jQuery variable selector

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to implement a jQuery AJAX script to open a link in a div. Only thing is the links are created dynamically using a PHP while loop, shown below:

```
<a id="topic<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" href="viewTopic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"><? echo $rows['topic']; ?></a>
```

The following code is the jQuery I am trying to use to create the ajax function. How can I create a dynamic selector like I have illustrated with PHP in the jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#topic<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>").click(function(){

        $("#subConList").html(loadAni).load('viewTopic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>');     
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `class` and `data-id` to your rows:

```
<a id="topic<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="topic" href="viewTopic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" data-id="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"><? echo $rows['topic']; ?></a>
```

Then select by the `class` and get the ID using `data`:

```
$('.topic').click(function() {
    var topicID = $(this).data('id');
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I think im getting close with this, my full jquery should look something like this then?         $(document).ready(function(){
$('.topic').click(function() {
    var topicID = $(this).data('id');
  
  $("#subConList").html(loadAni).load("topicID");  
 });
});

Comment: @Ciaran: That `load` part should look more like this: `.load('viewTopic.php?id=' + topicID)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('a[id^="topic"]').data('id')`;